# How to fix it? It’s about 0x API

Tags: 0x

[image]

I’m waiting online. It’s urgent

[image]

Comment: Have you tried their Discord  link.0x.org/Discord ?

It is interesting they ask you to post here https://gov.0x.org/t/for-technical-support-use-ethereum-stake-exchange/257

Comment: because of they let me to come here to ask a help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide us with a stack trace?

Try setting these env variables:

```
RFQT_API_KEY_WHITELIST_JSON=[]
PLP_API_KEY_WHITELIST_JSON=[]
```